# spelling correction with query in solr dismax parser

Tags: solr, dismax

i am using dismax parser to query the data in the field

```
<field name="object_description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

in standard query parser if i search for the term "object_description:Traditional" it gives me 13 results, also if i search for "object_description:Tradiional~1" it gives me 13 results which is correct

my question is how do i implement it using dismax parser.
can i do it in url or do i have to make changes in configurations??

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

dismax parser doesn't allow fuzzy search so i used edismax parser which supports it, but the query time increases a lot with fuzzy search